# While (true) forever loop expected body function error

Tags: c++, loops, ide, cs50

I'm new here. I am trying to do a forever loop with `while (true)` but can't seem to get it working. I have tried iterations without `int main(void)` as well.

```cpp
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
while (true)
{
printf("goddamnit\n")
}
```

```
~/ $ make goddamnit

[clang -ggdb3 -00 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno
-unused-parameter-Wno-unused-variable-Wshadow
goddamnit. c
-cryp
-Ics50 -1m -0 goddamnit
goddamnit.c:5:1: error: expected function body after function declarator
while (true)
A
1 error generated.
make:
*** \[‹builtin>; goddamnit\] Error 1][1]
```

**Same problem on my <> loop**

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 50) 
{
printf(“goddamnit\n”);
i++;
}
```

Note: Image in linked error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `{}` braces around your `main()` function's body, it needs to look more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{ // <-- add this
    while (true)
    {
        printf("goddamnit\n")
    }
} // <-- add this
```

Block statements like `if`, `for`, `while`, etc can omit `{}` when their body is a single statement.  Functions cannot do that.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, accidentally removed the semi colon. My professor seems to have left that out of the notes. https://ibb.co/T1rrdkn